# re:chill index,nothing is happening

Tags: c++, mingw32

I posted a question earlier about errors I was having with this program, but it worked yesterday, though it is no longer working today. I'm not sure what happened. here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float eqfunction(float, float);

int main() {
    float temperature;
    float windspeed;
    float returnchillindex;
    cout << "What is the temperature?"
    << "Must be in degrees fahrenheit";
    cin >> temperature;
    cout << "What is the wind speed?"
        << "In MPH.";
    cin >> windspeed;
    returnchillindex = eqfunction(temperature,windspeed);
    cout << returnchillindex;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}    

float eqfunction(float temperature, float windspeed){
    float windindex = 35.74f + 0.6215f * temperature;
    windindex = windindex - 35.75f * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16f);
    windindex = windindex + 0.4275f * temperature * std::pow(windspeed,0.16f);
    return windindex;
 }
```

this is what my compiler returns

> ```
> mingw32-g++.exe    -c C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\CodeBlocks\Exam1Part2.cpp -o C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\CodeBlocks\Exam1Part2.o
> mingw32-g++.exe  -o C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\CodeBlocks\Exam1Part2.exe C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\CodeBlocks\Exam1Part2.o   
> mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
> Please submit a full bug report.
> See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
> 0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
> ```

I don't understand what happened overnight.

Comment: "...but it worked yesterday, though it is no longer working today. I'm not sure what happened. I don't understand what happened overnight." - that does not make a real question. Did you upgrade your compiler? Did your machine crash and corrupt a file?

Comment: `mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error:` means it is a bug in the compiler, you should upgrade if possible. (check the version, I'm assuming you are using a very old compiler).

Comment: Seems to work with other installations of g++. For example: http://ideone.com/C2Alvl

Comment: thanks ill just look for a different compiler

Comment: what input do you give at the prompts?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine for me with `mingw32-g++`, but only after adding `#include <cstdlib>`. Without that, it complains about `system()` not being declared. I am using version 4.6.2